# GUID connection to Sqlite UniqueIdentifier causing query errors in NHibernate

Tags: c#, sqlite, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm working with someone's Sql Server database and a Fluent NHibernate mapped model which I test using (my own) SQLite database.

One table is called "Trad" and contains a "TradId" column which is a GUID type and so is declared as

```
 public virtual Guid TradId { get; set; }
```

and mapped:

```
Id(x => x.TradId).Column("TradID").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
```

for the purposes of testing in my SqlLite database it is declared using the "UniqueIdentifier" type which I believe maps to a string.

```
TradID    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL collate nocase,
```

Generally this works fine, except when any attempt is made by NHibernate to fetch by ID value, which comes up when connecting to child records.

Nhibernate spits out:

```
[...] WHERE this_.TradID = @p0;@p0 = ac3e30ff-e767-440f-ab1f-0000293c5a0c [Type: Guid (0)]
```

But this won't work because I think it needs to be handled as a string. 
Is there something I should be doing with the Sqlite connection to map this differently? Or is there something else I'm missing?

========================================================================

**Additional info**

I have a unit test with this code:

```
        var session = this.openSession;
        var trad = session.Query<Trad>()
            .FetchMany(x => x.TradInventeringList)
            .ToList()[0];

        var surveys = session.Query<TradInventering>()
            .Where(x => x.Trad.TradId == trad.TradId)
            .ToList();

        Assert.Greater(surveys.Count, 0);
```

This code runs if I have a session connected to my SqlServer (live) database, but fails against my Sqlite database.

I'm wondering if I need to add an IPropertyConvention based convention to my Fluently.Configure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After spending far too much time messing around with PropertyConventions I saw this [post](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof/learn/usage/sqlitewithguid) on Hibernating Rhinos.

The problem was solved by simply re-writing the FluentNhibernate SQLiteConfiguration to:

```
    config =
           SQLiteConfiguration.Standard
           .ConnectionString(
           "Data Source=" + databaseFilename + ";Version=3;BinaryGuid=False")
           .ShowSql();
```

Setting BinaryGuid=False handles the problem. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uuid.string generator? It uses GUIDs transformed into strings.

Comment: The UUID value is already in the database, so I don't need to generate it.
My question is how to let NHibernate know to handle the GUID field as a string when connected to Sqlite database instead of Sql Server.

Comment: Isn't that what I answered? uuid.string treats a GUID as a string.

Comment: Well then I'm not sure how you think I would use uuid.string to solve my problem. Can you give me a little more to go on?

Comment: Your problem is that you cannot use GUIDs as parameters, right? If so, you can map your ID property as as String but using the uuid.string generator. This way, when it wants to insert a new record, it will generate a GUID but will translate it to string and parameters in queries will always be of string type. But I may have misunderstood you... Do let me know!

Comment: I've added a bit more about my error. I don't know if that makes it more clear. 
Thanks for your continued interest!